# WER for wav2vec2-base model remains as 1 throughout the whole training process

Tags: machine-learning, nlp, speech-recognition, speech-to-text, windows-error-reporting

I am trying to run the **wav2vec2** speech recognition model as shared in https://huggingface.co/docs/transformers/tasks/asr

This is the [loss and WER](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mOA0V.png) during the training process, whereby the validation loss is reducing significantly, whereas the WER remains as 1.

I tried to print out the predicted and label values and this is what I got for the last 3 [outputs](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RAaaZ.png), which results in the WER = 1.

This is the set of parameters of the model. [model param](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Rk6ge.png).

What may actually go wrong here? Please help.. Thanks!

I have tried tuning the hyperparameters and hoping to reduce the WER.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank you for providing some useful information for troubleshooting.

- Your loss is reducing, which shows that the model is training, however your learning rate of `0.01` is very high. Consider changing this to something like `1e-5` as shown in the example on Hugging Face.
- The other thing I noticed was that all your input text is in `UPPER CASE LIKE THIS`. Depending on the training data used for the original model, it may not be expecting upper case text. Try lower-casing your text to see if that yields a lower WER.
- Your `save_steps` and `eval_steps` are also both far too high. This is how far the model "looks backwards" to evaluate - with a count of 1 on both these parameters, the model doesn't have enough history to compare better predictions. Increase these parameters and try again.

Comment: Thank you so much for the answer Kathy. Very much appreciated! Yes, I have tried to adjust the parameters as suggested and let it run a bit longer. and finally I can see some improvement in the WER. 

Thanks again!

Comment: You're very welcome! Good luck! Please mark that as the accepted answer if that's working for you, as it helps other people.